Does NimbusJwtDecoder work with hashed secret?
I am using NimbusJwtDecoder do verify signature of JWT token,
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hmacSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),(String) JCA_ALGORITHM_MAPPINGS.get(algo));
return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKeySpec).macAlgorithm((MacAlgorithm) algo).build();

And then i am using it like:
nimubsDecoder.decode(jwtToken);

The JWT is signed using MacAlgorithm algo, but the problem is - client is using raw secret to createa and sign JWT, but the server is working with hashed version of the key ( sha256 ), is nimbus working with hashed version of secretKey or does it require RAW secret key to verify signature?
THanks for help

You either use a symmetric key or an asymmetric key (strongly recommend asymmetric) you use the private key to sign it, and the public key to verify it. No a hashed key does not work. Hashes are one way algorithms. And when you say client, who is the client? you need to update your question with more context, voted to close
